# Where is the documentation about removing arguments from a WriteToken signature, as shown in an official ASIO example?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, asio, boost-bind

In this example :
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html#boost_asio.tutorial.tutdaytime3.removing_unused_handler_parameters

It is written :

> You may have noticed that the error, and bytes_transferred parameters are not used in the body of the handle_write() function. If parameters are not needed, it is possible to remove them from the function

However, it seems like everywhere else (
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write.html https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/WriteHandler.html
), the documentation says that the function-like should match the signature.

I tried with an empty lambda, and indeed, it complains about the signature. *Is it boost::bind that allows async_write to call it discarding the argument ?*

Where is it documented in the official boost documentation ?

Comment: You see just above the bit you quoted, where it discusses removing unused placeholders from the `async_write()` call - did you change that to match the new `handle_write` signature?

Comment: @Useless I mean, it works, my question is only "Where is it documented why it works ?".

Comment: The "official" documentation will be at Boost Bind where it describes that any unbound arguments will simply be dropped. E.g. the various examples here make it pretty clear: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.purpose.using_bind_with_functions_and_fu - The whole thing really has nothing to do with Asio.

Comment: Oh nice. You edited that into the question already. Well. I guess that settles it.

Comment: So the code that works is the code in the Boost.Asio documentation, but when you tried using a lambda instead of a bind functor it failed, and you're really asking about where the Boost.Bind documentation describes the feature _used_ by Boost.Asio? Is that right?

Comment: @Useless Yes : I never questioned if the code worked, I knew it from the beginning it does. But the doc never says it's thanks to bind. The very bind that in *ALL* other language (especially functional ones) only attach arguments to a function, not allowing to call it with whatever extra arguments. The doc of bind is 638 lines, 4769 words long. The info is in a small sentence in the middle of a section named "Using bind with functions and function pointers" (no "argument" nor "signature" keywords), with examples that don't explicitly present this feature...

Comment: I'm just clarifying your question, which _also_ has only a small sentence in the middle saying what the actual question is. Otherwise the first half is about Asio, and includes a claim that some code (not shown) had some error (not shown). It's a lot more work to understand what the question is than really seems necessary!

Comment: @Useless uh... where is it stated the code has an error ? (and btw, what code ?). I only expose two quotes from the doc appearing to be contradictory... The two only questions in my post are "is it boost::bind that allows async_write to call it discarding the argument ?" and "Where is it documented in the official boost documentation ?". I can't see what is misleading here... (and yes, the first part was about ASIO because at the time I asked, I did not know it was unrelated. especially since asio provides placeholder for bind...)

Comment: _I tried with an empty lambda, and indeed, it complains about the signature_ = hidden code had a secret error. I know that's not your actual question, but where you ended up is only tangentially related to where you started.

Answer (score 1):

As supposed in the question it's `boost::bind` that allows it.

[Is using boost::bind to pass more arguments than expected safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394367/is-using-boostbind-to-pass-more-arguments-than-expected-safe)

**The result of boost::bind can be sefely called with more arguments :**

> Note that, in the last example, the function object produced by bind(g, _1, _1, _1) does not contain references to any arguments beyond the first, but it can still be used with more than one argument. Any extra arguments are silently ignored, just like the first and the second argument are ignored in the third example.

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.purpose.using_bind_with_functions_and_fu

Since a bound function with `boost::bind` can be called with extra argument, the compiler does not complain.